# How does heat conduction take place in sound wave propagation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, acoustics

I am new to wave mechanics. It would be of real help if someone could elaborate, although not in too much detail(as I am still a beginner) regarding the conduction of heat during rarefractions and compressions. What I am looking for is not a mathematical explanation, but a visual one, with which I can visualize as to how the process happens. I am not able to understand and visualize how the temperature increases/decreases during a rarefreaction or compression, and how it is adiabatic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As you might know, a sound wave is an example of a longitudinal wave. In brief, a longitudinal wave is a wave in which the particles of the medium vibrate( a more appropriate terminology would be '*perform a simple harmonic motion*') in the same plane where the wave travels. This figure illustrates that:
[image]

Here, you see a tuning fork set into vibration which consequently sets the particles of the medium around it in vibrations as well and this finally results in a longitudinal wave being formed.

---

If we focus more on how this happens, we see that when the sound wave is initiated, (you can simply visualise this by thinking of talking to someone) When we speak, the air particles right in front of our mouth are set into vibrations.

These particles then set their neighbouring particles into vibrations, and so on. This gif illustrates this:

[image]

As you can see, in the region of compressions, the density is increased. And as you might know, any particle of any medium has the property that it has some amount of vibrational kinetic energy. In the compressions, particles are packed in a smaller region which means more pressure(as the density is increased here). Consequently, this increases the temperature in this region. which also results in more energy being trapped.

Also, this happens so fast that this thermal energy does not have any time to flow out from the compressed region. The same applies in the case of rarefied regions. Consequently, it is safe to assume this to be adiabatic which is what Laplace did to correct Newton's formula for speed of sound in medium.

---

Remember that these variations are quite small and negligible. Think! Have you ever felt the temperature suddenly increasing/decreasing while speaking to someone?

Comment: That explains that temperature changes occur and when, but not how its generated and where it comes from. The variations may be negligible during speaking, but they are quite noticeable in a vortex tube. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I believe the part about the density getting increased which results in more collisions of the particles should explain that. I have tried to provide simple explanations as she mentioned in her post that she wanted to visualise how this works, I have also added the gif which shows how the compressions and rarefactions are getting formed and transmitted. You're right about the vortex tube but I preferred to give a rather simple case as an example. I would be more than happy if you could give more suggestions so that I can improve my answer :)

Comment: I was hoping you had the answer to that. I have my own hypothesis on how thermal energy travels from one particle to another in a gas, why it tends to rise with rising pressure and why there is a speed to sound. But you know the reputation of such thoughts, so I am hoping for someone to correct me or come up with established relevant science known for ages. Conductive propagation of thermal energy in gases is observed and described, but not explained. More particular, the way thermal energy behaves in gas. It does weird things, like in the vortex tube.

Comment: Well I'm myself, dont have a lot of knowledge in this field and that's all I had. Maybe you can raise a bounty on this question to get it more attention and maybe then, you can get a more clear, descriptive answer which explains the more complex reasoning behind this! :)

Comment: Are you kidding me? :) Raising a bonus on that might get me banned. I was just hoping this exact question would draw an answer from someone who can shed a light on what's behind where all common knowledge stops. Lots of people know what influences the speed of sound, but no one seems to know where it comes from and why it is so stable or even why it exists in the first place. Your explanation, which I find beautiful by the way., doesn't do that either. To me it feels like a 'the emperor's new clothes' kind of thing. Am I really the only one who is seeing this?

Comment: @Prajwal Tiwari, isn't an adiabatic process one, In which there is no flow of heat between the system and the surroundings at all? How is the above process an adiabatic one?

Comment: And yes, where does the heat energy come from anyway?

Comment: Is it that, when the air in front of the speaker gets compressed, the molecules move pretty close to each other. Hence the repulsive forces come into play, thus the molecules repel and move away with a great velocity, increasing the magnitude of kinetic energy of the molecules, thus increasing the temperature?  This process makes it adiabatic as well, because the heat isnt borrowed from an external source, but sort of created from within, if you know what I mean

Comment: @ Prajwal Tiwari,   In your GIF the speed of the wave is determined by the amplitude and the frequency of the movement of the wave generator. In sound the speed of the wave depends entirely on the substance it travels through, indifferent to the amplitude or the frequency of the sound. That is where heat conduction takes place. What is hardest to grasp is, that all air is always moving at the speed of sound. Besides that, it may move in large volumes called wind, or close to objects called airflow.

Comment: @NishaPrakash Yes! An adiabatic process is a thermodynamic process which involves the transfer of energy without transfer of heat or mass to the surrounding. And that's what's happening here. If you look more closely at what a 'wave' actually is, you'll find out that it's nothing but a disturbance in a medium, which carries energy. A more easy to understand use of words would be that wave is a vehicle for energy to travel without actual movement of the particles of the medium from the source to the destination. So that's where the energy comes from.

Comment: @NishaPrakash coming to the adiabatic part, as I mentioned in my answer, these pressure variations are so fast thus not allowing time for any heat to get transferred at all! Thus, making this adiabatic. Coming to your second comment, yes, during the compressions, the particles of the medium are concentrated in a smaller space(which is what we mean when we say that the density is increased) and as you might know, all the particles have vibrational kinetic energy. In this small space, collisions take place hence making the temperature higher.

Comment: One would focus more on the property of the particles of a wave rather than 'repulsions driving the particles back with a great velocity'  The particles of these wave execute their own simple harmonic motion. Which basically means they are moving back and forth about a fixed point which is called their mean position. To visualise this, pick just one particle(the red ones are provided for this purpose) in the lower GIF I attached in my answer, and just focus on its motion. You'll see that it's just going back and forth about a fixed point.

Comment: @ Prajwal Tiwari The GIF does not show sound propagation. Whatever it is that moves in the GIF is not sound, because sound moves differently. The speed of sound does not at all relate to the source of the sound. Not in the slightest. It depends entirely on qualities of the propagating medium, its temperature, composition, density etc. The GIF shows that in half the same way a broken clock is right twice a day.

Comment: @Berend the gif was put there only for visualisation of how a longitudinal wave(a sound wave is also a longitudinal wave) propagates. That also helps visualise how the compressions/rarefactions occur. A sound wave's propagation would rather be a 3 dimensional spherical figure. You're right that the speed of the sound doesn't depend on the source, Laplace's formula clearly states the sound's speed's relation with temperature, and the medium.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just so it is there, controversial as it is.

The way heat conduction takes place in sound wave propagation, is by a sequence of condensations and evaporations of particles as a consequence of local increase and decrease of pressure caused by the wave. As the energy provoking the condensation may vary, but the energy released in evaporation may not, the difference is shared by the particles involved as thermal energy. There is a radiating component involved too, but that is in comparison negligibly small. This concludes the full extend of heat conduction, caused by wave propagation.

All credits/discredits to the author.
No references.